# Is it safe to ride on wheels with rusted spoke eyelets?

Tags: wheels, wheel-building, preventative-maintenance, wheel-truing

I bought an old Bianchi with 26" wheels and I’m finding it hard to find a replacement with max width 23 mm tires and an old 6 speed freewheel

I was trying to true the wheels but the nipples where rounded so I ended up breaking them with some pliers. My PoC of putting some nipples I had seems to work and I could buy new spokes and nipples:
[image]

But I'm concerned about the rusted eyelets:
[image]

Is it safe to ride with them in that state? In case it is not, can they be replaced?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the rust is not a safety issue. It's fine.

They're not replaceable in any kind of practical sense. Double eyelets or sockets such as those pictured are formed to match a specific distance between rim walls, and so they are more or less specific to the rims they come on, and finding replacements is impractical or impossible. Single eyelets (not what you have) may have been available as replacements in some times and places. They're installed into rims in a relatively simple peening process.

Comment: Actually, they can be replaced with only moderate effort.  But not really worth the effort.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: Are they not riveted with special tools?

Comment: @Michael - Not usually.

Comment: Where do you get the replacements from?

Comment: @ojs: a new rim LOLZ